# Function that detects when variable change?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working on a small inventory system for a game (not the question however) and have made a method that uses an item which then decrements the size of the ItemStack by one. Because the stack size changes I need to re calculate the stack's weight and overall value and I was wondering if there was a better way to do it than how I have done it? Is there a way to detect when the stack_size changes and update the weight and value, perhaps using a decorator or something? Help is much appreciated.

```
def use_item_stack(self):
    self.stack_size -= 1
    self.stack_weight = self.item_weight * self.stack_size
    self.stack_value = self.item_value * self.stack_size
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use properties!

```
class Game(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._stack_size = 5

    @property
    def stack_size(self):
        return self._stack_size

    @stack_size.setter
    def stack_size(self, val):
        self._stack_size = val
        #do some more updates of other things
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, I completely forgot about the property decorator! Thank you for reminding me of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done seems logical enough, if the stack was updated, so its overall weight needs to be recalculated right there and then.

You could however have a `decorator` and have it wrapped around all "stack operations", so whenever they update the stack the wrapper will as well update the total weight:

```
def stack_sensitive(fn):
    def wrapper():
        ss = STACK_SIZE
        fn()
        if STACK_SIZE != ss: pass # recalculate
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be a way to use decorators and I tried something similar to this but could not get it to work.